# Regex replace match with match + addons

Tags: php, regex, sed, grep

I would like to replace case-insensitive let's say mix:

```
text StmiXx and some more mIxx text
```

after regex replacement:

```
text St<font color="red">miX</font>x and some more <font color="red>mIx</font> text
```

code:

```
$string = "text StmiXx and some more mIxx text";
$pattern = "/mix/i";
$replacement = "<font color=\"red\">match</font>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

How can this be done with regex? I also would like to try this with (Linux)sed or is there also a way with egrep, grep.

egrep has an option --color=always but not custom highlight.

Answer (score 2):

You were close! Here is how you can do it in PHP:

```
$string = "text StmiXx and some more mIxx text";
$pattern = "/(mix)/i";
$replacement = "<font color=\"red\">$1</font>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

In the pattern the parentheses can be used to capture the content (group). Then you can reference the group by the number of repeated parentheses. In this case we have only one group. That's why in the replacement I used `$1` to reference the only capture group we have in our pattern.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your issue, please feel free to accept it by clicking on the empty tick icon below the vote count on the left side of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
s="text StmiXx and some more mIxx text"
echo "$s" | sed -e 's!\([mM][iI][xX]\)!<font color="red">\1</font>!g'
```

**Edit:**

To perform the substitution and only print the lines that match:

```
sed -n -e 's!\([mM][iI][xX]\)!<font color="red">\1</font>!g;/[mM][iI][xX]/p'
```

And to get only the first N lines, you can pipe this to head or to:

```
sed -n -e '1,10p'
```

Comment: Is there also an option which would print the first 10 matches. I looked man sed, info sed, http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt. For invert match I add ^ in [^mM]

Comment: Or the first n matches like egrep has -m NUM option.

Comment: @broadand: if you want to print the first 10 matches, add a `| head -n 10`at the end ;-).

Comment: Yes but I get sed: couldn't write 157 items to stdout: Broken pipe
sed: couldn't write 80 items to stdout: Broken pipe

Comment: @broadand: sorry, my previous comment was in regard with another question that I work on previously and as you point out, once head is done with its 10 first line, is ended so sed gets Broken Pipe.

Comment: @broadand: instead of piping to head, pipe to another sed: `sed -n -e '1,10p'`.  Sed will keep reading the input to the end, avoiding the Broken Pipe.  But how many lines of input do you have, on which UNIX are you, and which shell do you use ?  With 385 lines, on cygwin and bash, I do not get Broken Pipe.

Comment: Well I would like to use sed as I now use egrep because sed is much faster when processing large files:     egrep -i $search -m 5 --line-buffered --color=always $file     I would like to get first 5 matches but I use sed -e 's!\('$1'\)!<font color="red"><strong>\1</strong></font>!g' $line 2>/dev/null | head -n 5 this only gives me first 5 lines which are not necessery matches. I use kubuntu 11.04/bash

Comment: Wow perfect solution, thank you jfgagne. I have about 30 files each 20000 lines on average.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "text StmiXx and some more mIxx text";
$pattern = "/(mix)/i";
$replacement = "<font color=\"red\">$1</font>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Had to stare a minute to actually figure out if something was wrong inside the code :)

$1 represents the first thing the pattern finds inside ()

For instance, if you want to change it to m-ix for some reason, you could so like this:

```
$string = "text StmiXx and some more mIxx text";
$pattern = "/(m)(ix)/i";
$replacement = "<font color=\"red\">$1-$2</font>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Thank you Robin, I hope regex is fast, because I got txt files on average about 5 MB size.